# How can I execute N number of jobs at the same time in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, multithreading, queue, supervisord

In our project, we need to run N number of job at the same time.

Currently, we have used supervisor workers. In this, if there are 100 jobs then they execute one by one.

We want all jobs executed at the same time instead of one by one.

I have also tried multiple queue, like:

```
queue:work --queue=default,first,second
```

```
dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('first'));
dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('second'));
```

I am still not getting output like we want. What would be a suggestion for this?

Comment: According to [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#supervisor-configuration), you should be able to specify the number of process using the `numproc` confing. I doubt you have 100 available CPU, so it won't be "at the same time", but it might help speed up the process.

Comment: If I may ask, why do you absolutly want the 100 jobs to be run at the exact same time ?

Comment: @Nicolas It's not fixed.I just say 100 for example

Comment: Still, is there a reason why all the jobs needs to run at the exact same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Run Multiple Workers: To process jobs from different queues simultaneously, you need to run multiple worker processes, each listening to a specific queue. You can do this using the queue: work Artisan command: php artisan queue:work

Comment: Hi. It seems that you forgot to add the Artisan command from your answer. Remember to have a second read before submitting.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of my mistake @JMCampos

Comment: @AbdullahAhmed But are you planning on fixing your mistake?  If not, you should delete your answer.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds added